# Search lightswitch field with disabled value

Tags: search, lightswitch

I want to exclude some entires from search, so I add a field `hideFromSearch` and enable `Use this field’s values as search keywords`

It works when I search like

```
Entry::find()->search('hideFromSearch::1')->all();
```

But it doesn't work when I search like

```
Entry::find()->search('hideFromSearch::0')->all();
```

Always return empty array.
I also tried

```
Entry::find()->search('hideFromSearch::""')->all();
```

No luck.

Craft version: Craft Pro 3.7.55.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the lightswitch field to the `search` query, add a separate condition as [recommended in the documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/lightswitch-fields.html#querying-elements-with-lightswitch-fields).

```php
Entry::find()
    ->search('my search query')
    ->hideFromSearch(true)
    ->all();
```

Use `true` and `false` to only find entries where the lightswitch is turned on or off, respectively. Then you can deselect `Use this field’s values as search keywords`, as this condition won't require the search index.

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks